# Node request returns weird characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

```
var request = require("request");
var url  = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29";
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

On my ubuntu machine I get

```
�+��O��%
```

And on my PC (windows) I get

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$6.38","volume":"2,370","median_price":"$6.97"}
```

What's the problem? I'm sure it worked before..

Comment: Looks like your Ubuntu console is using a different encoding and/or font. http://askubuntu.com/questions/87227/switch-encoding-of-terminal-with-a-command

Comment: Are you actually using and testing the exact same code in both cases? My initial hunch was that the first one is somehow a compressed version of the second one, but that seems unlikely. Could you run your node script's output through `hexdump`?

Comment: Works for me on a clean Ubuntu build both within Sublime: http://d.pr/i/978j and Terminal: http://d.pr/i/syGT on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.